How can I make this python code more efficient without importing any libraries?
I wrote a python program to print the cubes of numbers in a specified range. I want to get this result using only a single list. I know that I could've used numpy for the cbrt() function but I don't want to use libraries to do that.
How can I make my code more efficient without using libraries?
cubes = [x ** 3 for x in range(1, 11)]# list comprehension to store cubes
num = [k for k in range(1, 11)]# list comprehension for numbers whose cubes are being stored

for i in range(len(cubes)):# loop for printing
    print(f"The cube of {num[i]} is {cubes[i]}.\n")


There are some things to improve about this, but it won't become much more efficient than this. Is it too slow for you?

if the goal is to print the values of the lists just do everything in a single loop (without creating the list s)

You can store tuples of (x, x ** 3) instead of using 2 separate ones. The improvement is minimal, but it does use only 1 list.

@matszwecja I'd just use enumerate…

@deceze but that would require knowing the range used for cubes

@matszwecja I'd expect that information to be known, but anyway, this is all micro-optimisation anyway. x ** 3 is the heaviest operation here anyway, and that's hard to optimise.

@deceze n*n*n is marginally faster than n**3 with Python 3.12.3 on M2

@SIGHUP Can't reproduce, same setup. Nothing worth worrying about IMO.

You don't need 2 lists. Also, x * x * x is marginally faster than x ** 3 on some platforms. Therefore:
cubes = [x * x * x for x in range(1, 11)]

for n, v in enumerate(cubes, 1):
    print(f"The cube of {n} is {v}")

...is probably as fast as you can get.
In fact, if your only objective is to print the cubes then you don't need a list at all. Just calculate the values for each print()
i.e.,
for n in range(1, 11):
    print(f"The cube of {n} is {n*n*n}")


thank you for your help. Your knowledge has made me a better coder.
